# CorePlot date labels incorrect when plotting data without weekends/holidays

Tags: core-plot

I have created a CPTTradingRangePlot using the up-to-date sample code as an example.  The sample uses a starting reference date and an index to draw the y-axis labels.  The Y-axis calculates on calendar days and I can't find a way to change this. The problem is the data is missing weekends and holidays and thus the y-axis becomes out of sync.  Is it possible to account for this?

Comment: Do you want to remove the weekends from the scale, or just skip over the empty days leaving a blank space?

Comment: I would like to remove the weekends and holidays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your datasource should convert the date range into a continuous range by dropping out the days you don't want. For instance, days 1 to 5 might map to indexes 0-4, followed by days 8-12 mapping to 5-9. Days 6 and 7 are ignored (e.g., a weekend). For labels, you can either make custom labels that match up with the correct points, or make a custom `NSNumberFormatter` that reverses the range conversion and formats the label correctly.